# Firebase functions en local

Tags: firebase, npm

Me gustaría hacer mis pruebas de firebase en local. El hosting me funciona correctamente pero las funciones no.
Estoy siguiendo [los pasos que da google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator?hl=es-419)

Este el error que me da: `

```
   C:\..\functions\server_part> firebase serve --only functions,hosting

=== Serving from 'C:\..\functions\server_part'...

!  functions: Cannot start emulator. Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
```

Al intentar instalar `grpc`

me aparecen unos cuantos errores, pero creo que el mas importante es:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\txema\Documents\broccoli-music\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\node_modules\grpc\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\txema\Documents\broccoli-music\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\node_modules\grpc\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\txema\Document\broccoli-music\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\node_modules\grpc\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\txema\Documents\broccoli-music\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\node_modules\grpc\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\txema\Documents\broccoli-music\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\node_modules\grpc\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
```

Tengo instalado el visual Studio y el net framework 4.7

Muchas gracias por la atención

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que comprobar si tienes instalada la versión 2.0 de .NET Framework, como te dice el error.
Para comprobarlo fíjate aquí en regedit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```

Que tengas instalada la versión 4.7 no quiere decir que tengas la 2.0, necesitas también la 2.0 a parte.